# how to sign android rom.zip file?

Tags: android

For some reason I need to change android rom zip file. But when I change add/remove content, my rom cant be installed. Its need to be resigned.

I want to know if there is any simple command in Mac OS by which I can sign the rom.zip file

Comment: Pardon me if its a duplicate..

Answer (score 4):

I guess you don't have eclipse installed (it can sign your applications automatically)

- First, download the signing tools and extract them anywhere
  http://goo.gl/lRNlE8
- Copy your zip or apk files to signing tools folder

And run the following command:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar signapk.jar -w testkey.x509.pem testkey.pk8 my_rom.zip my_signed_rom.zip
```

Replace my_rom.zip with the name of the file you want to sign and my_signed_rom.zip with the new name you want to give to your zip or apk.

Please note the signing tools contain test keys, make sure to replace them with your own.

If you want to know more about app signing, I suggest you go directly to the source:
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html